# Should the model or controller be responsible for sending emails?

Tags: model-view-controller

In a MVC web application, I often send emails.

I usually do it in the controller, as I load all my views from the controller (including email views).

Now, however, I have some code where the email sends from the model.

Which tier is email generally sent from? Does it matter? Does it *need* to be consistent?

Comment: Well it depends, does the "user" send a email, then sees a confirmation page? If so, it should be done in Controller (send email, show confirmation view). If it's a background/admin thing, the controller should call a method in a service layer, as the below answer states.

Comment: I would argue that the actual sending of the email should still be done in a service. The controller should instantiate the service, pass along the data to it, get a response and then call the view to render passing along the resultant data.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A controller should ideally be like an operator that connects a view to a model. This either belongs in the model or service layer.

I would argue that this belongs in the Model layer only if you have a model object that is solely responsible for sending e-mails. You don't want to comingle presentation and logic, that's the whole point of separation of concerns in Model-View-Controller.

This type of logic should reside in a service layer. You could then use dependency injection to inject the service into the controller and call EmailSenderService.sendEmail();